# Sort text in second column based on values in first column

Tags: python, pandas

in python i would like to separate the text in different rows based on the values of the first number. So:

```
Harry went to School 100
Mary sold goods 50
Sick man
```

using the provided information below:

```
number  text
1   Harry
1   Went
1   to
1   School
1   100
2   Mary
2   sold
2   goods
2   50
3   Sick
3   Man

for i in xrange(0, len(df['number'])-1):
    if df['number'][i+1] == df['number'][i]:
          # append text (e.g Harry went to school 100)
    else:
          # new row (Mary sold goods 50)
```

Comment: It looks like you're using pandas - is that correct?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html),

```
for name,group in df.groupby(df['number']):
    print ' '.join([i for i in group['text']])
```

**Result**

```
Harry Went to School 100
Mary sold goods 50
Sick Man
```